# Python SQLite3 error with bindings; File not being processed line by line as specified

Tags: python, binding, sqlite, line

I am attempting to populate a SQLite3 database using Python code, but I am getting errors.  Below is a snippet of the code.  When I run this and try to submit my list 'L2', I get

"Error Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 10 supplied."

So, when I changed it to have a list called 'red' with the listed items (in code below), I still get an error...this time "current statement uses 3, and there are 2 supplied."  I can change the contents of the list 'red' to anything I want, and it still has the same error!!

So, clearly there is a problem with the identification of a 'binding' and how to count them.

```
Code is:-



import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('Sequences.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE test2') 
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE test2 
            (seq_id TEXT, sequence TEXT, qual_score TEXT)''')

f = ('path to file')
motif = '@HWI'
flags = ['+', '<', ',', '?', '>']   

with open(f, 'r') as df:
     data = df.readlines()
     L2 = list()

     for line in data:
         line = line.strip()
         if motif in line:
             L2.append(line)
         elif not any(flag in line for flag in flags):
             L2.append(line)
         else:
             if any(flag in line for flag in flags[1:]):
                 L2.append(line)
                 red = ['green', 'blue', 'happy']
                 cur.executemany('INSERT into test2 VALUES (?,?,?)', red)
                 del L2[:]
                 print 'END'
con.comitt()
con.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Why did it get edited so that the second error I get (on modified code, not shown here but explained in the text) is now in the code block???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  I need each row to be contained in a tuple, inside of a list.

so, for the final code block, it should be:

```
     else:
         if any(flag in line for flag in flags[1:]):
             L2.append(line)
             L2 = tuple(L2)
             L3 = []
             L3.append(L2)
             cur.executemany('INSERT into test2 VALUES (?,?,?)', L3)
             con.commit()
             del L2[:]
             print 'END'
```